# How to escape ">" character in postgres version 9.2

Tags: xml, postgresql, xpath

How do i make the `>` sign display as is in PG version 9.2 ? I do not want it to show as `&gt;`.

Query in postgreSQL

```
SELECT 
XPATH ('/BehaviorReportingRanges/BehaviorReportingRange/Range/text()', 
xmlparse(content 
'<BehaviorReportingRanges> 
  <BehaviorReportingRange> 
   <Range>> 3</Range> 
  </BehaviorReportingRange> 
</BehaviorReportingRanges>'))
```

Result in version 9.1:

```
{"> 3"} -- desired result
```

result in version 9.2.3:

```
"{"&gt; 3"}" -- not desired result
```

any pointers please ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: It looks like libxml its self is doing that transformation; try feeding the input into `xmllint` to see what I mean. I didn't think unescaped trailing `>` was legal well-formed XML anyway. Passing `--noent` to `xmllint` doesn't have any effect, it's still escaped on output.

Comment: I'm surprised that Postgres 9.1 accepts to parse the invalid XML... Your desired result is simply incorrect. It **must** be escaped.

Comment: I see.. Could you also help with, how to i escape it ? Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you
`CREATE LANGUAGE plpythonu;` , you can then do the following:

```
create or replace function unescape(x varchar)
    returns varchar language plpythonu as $$
from xml.sax.saxutils import unescape
return unescape(x)
$$;
```

Then, your query can become:

```
SELECT unescape( concat( (
XPATH ('/BehaviorReportingRanges/BehaviorReportingRange/Range/text()', 
xmlparse(content 
'<BehaviorReportingRanges> 
  <BehaviorReportingRange> 
   <Range>> 3</Range> 
  </BehaviorReportingRange> 
</BehaviorReportingRanges>')) )[1]
 ) );
```

You need to add the indexing to select the element from the array result of xpath, and the concat is to convert from xml to string datatype.

You can also apply the unescape function directly -- but the resulting string is the formatted xml array.